# How to disable - Django Haystack from searching, if facet is selected

Tags: python, django, solr

Im Using Django Haystack in Oscar CMS project, and i have problem with the way its - returning selected facets data from search.

When i dont select any product in menu, the order of facets(item class) from solr is that [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5r2Z.png)

```
T-Shirt
Classic
```

But when i select Classic product, solr is moving selected facets to first position in list - like that [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjWpU.png)

```
Classic
T-Shirt
```

so its changing order, and this is a problem - is it possible to disalbe haystack from changing initial data - when no queries/facets are selected, so they all would be static ! Or maybe there are other options to solve that - Please Help me out !

Code Sample(first its HTML context data handler):

---

```
 def get_search_context_data(self, context_object_name=None):

 context = {'form': self.search_form,
            'paginator':self.paginator,
            'page_obj': self.page}

 BrowseCategoryForm = get_class('search.forms', 'SearchForm')

 def __init__(self, request_data, full_path):
            self.choice_form = self.get_choice_form(request_data, search_queryset)

 def get_choice_form(self,request_data,search_queryset):
     form_class = BrowseCategoryForm
     data = self.results.facet_counts()['fields']['product_class']
     kwargs = {
                'data': request_data,
                'selected_facets': request_data.getlist("selected_facets"),
                'searchqueryset': search_queryset,
                'facet_counts':data
            }
     return form_class(**kwargs)
```

Code Sample(SearchForm itself)

---

class SearchForm(FacetedSearchForm):

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.facet_counts = kwargs.pop("facet_counts",[])
            super(SearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for field_value, count in self.facet_counts:
        choices=[]
        field_url = 'product_class_exact:%s' % field_value
        choices.append((field_url,field_value))
    self.fields['selected_facets'] = forms.ChoiceField(
            label=_("Sort by"), choices=choices,
            widget=forms.Select(), required=False)
```

CodeSample(Haystack Query, to init facets search)

---

```
def facet_counts(self):
    """
    Returns the facet counts found by the query.

    This will cause the query to execute and should generally be used when
    presenting the data.
    """
    if self.query.has_run():
        return self.query.get_facet_counts()
    else:
        clone = self._clone()
        return clone.query.get_facet_counts()
```

---

CodeSample(Haystack backend, to get facets)

```
def get_facet_counts(self):
    """
    Returns the facet counts received from the backend.

    If the query has not been run, this will execute the query and store
    the results.
    """
    if self._facet_counts is None:
        self.run()
    return self._facet_counts

def run(self, spelling_query=None, **kwargs):
    """Builds and executes the query. Returns a list of search results."""
    final_query = self.build_query()
    search_kwargs = self.build_params(spelling_query=spelling_query)

    if kwargs:
        search_kwargs.update(kwargs)

    results = self.backend.search(final_query, **search_kwargs)
    print("results Run",results)
    self._results = results.get('results', [])
    self._hit_count = results.get('hits', 0)
    self._facet_counts = self.post_process_facets(results)
    self._spelling_suggestion = results.get('spelling_suggestion', None)
```

Code Sample(Solr_backend , acctual search):

---

```
def search(self, query_string, **kwargs):
    if len(query_string) == 0:
        return {
            'results': [],
            'hits': 0,
        }

    search_kwargs = self.build_search_kwargs(query_string, **kwargs)
    try:
        raw_results = self.conn.search(query_string, **search_kwargs)
    except (IOError, SolrError) as e:
        if not self.silently_fail:
            raise

        self.log.error("Failed to query Solr using '%s': %s", query_string, e, exc_info=True)
        raw_results = EmptyResults()

    return self._process_results(raw_results, highlight=kwargs.get('highlight'), result_class=kwargs.get('result_class', SearchResult), distance_point=kwargs.get('distance_point'))
```

Notice that - facet_counts - is that acctual  facet - data that is being reordered when is selected !

If there is need in providing any other data - please let me know, i hope someone can help me out in this, im stuck with it - for more then a week !

Answer (score 0):

You may make additional filter for SearchQuerySet without current facet